# How do I enable autoescaping in templates with a .jhtml extension in Flask?

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

[The Flask docs state](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#jinja-setup):

> autoescaping is enabled for all templates ending in .html, .htm, .xml as well as .xhtml

How do I enable autoescaping for templates ending with a .jhtml extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@Cagez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13223175/1944) I was able to come up with a robust (and recommended) solution.

According to [a post on the Flask mailing list](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/1/29/select-jinja-autoescape/#f101cd7788e8dfa062ed32041eb1bc67), the way to do this is to override `flask.Flask.select_jinja_autoescape()`. The linked snippet in that post demonstrating how to [override which templates are autoescaped](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/41/) didn't quite work, so I came up with the following, which does work:

```
class JHtmlEscapingFlask(Flask):

    def select_jinja_autoescape(self, filename):
        if filename is None:
            return False
        if filename.endswith('.jhtml'):
            return True
        return Flask.select_jinja_autoescape(self, filename)

app = JHtmlEscapingFlask(__name__)
```

I put this at the top of my main Flask app file, replacing the usual `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: Although I accepted my own answer here, I relied on the useful information posted by @Cagez so please give him an upvote if you find this question and/or answer useful.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you can set the file extensions with the 'autoescape' option when creating the app.  Take a look at the create_jinja_environment() method at https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py